# How does TypeScript infer the type of `this`?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, this, type-inference

The inference strategy of `this` in TypeScript is confusing to me, for example:

```
class A {
    s: String
    constructor() {
        this.s = "this is fine"
    }
    f() {
        console.log(this.s)
    }
}

let a = new A

a.f() // -> this is fine

let f1 = (new A).f
f1() // -> undefined
```

If you put the code into TypeScript [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/), and check the type of `this` inside `f()`, you can see that it's inferred to be of type `this: this`, which means the subtype of `A`.

In this situation, I think it means `this` is bind to `A`, and can't refer to the global object. Otherwise, `this` should be inferred to be of type `this: Any`.

But actually, as shown in the invocation of `f1()`, if the function `f` is invoked outside the context of `A`, it could still be the global object.

So in my opinion, the inferred type of `this` inside `f()` should be `this: Any`, not `this: this`. And only if the function `f` is defined with arrow function could it be inferred to be `this: this`. For example:

```
class A {
    s: String
    constructor() {
        this.s = "this is fine"
    }
    f = () => {
        console.log(this.s)
    }
}

let a = new A

a.f() // -> this is fine

let f1 = (new A).f
f1() // -> this is fine
```

So, is this a bug or a design feature? How does TypeScript infer the type of `this` actually?

Comment: `is this a bug or a design feature?` it's designed to work the same as javascript

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for your tips. I understand that `this` is determined by the context at call-site dynamically, in some order of precedence, as illustrated in quite some [articles](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch2.md#review-tldr). But I want to know how does TypeScript infer the type of `this` statically.

Comment: Sorry, I get what you're asking now ... because typescript is typed you want to know how typescript knows what type `this` is at any given moment

Comment: @JaromandaX Yes, that's exactly what I want to know. Because in the example I gave, the behavior is counter-intuitive to me.

Comment: @mpm I tried, it's `Window` object in Chrome: [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20s%3A%20String%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.s%20%3D%20%22this%20is%20fine%22%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20f()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log(this.s)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20new%20A%0D%0A%0D%0Aa.f()%20%2F%2F%20-%3E%20this%20is%20fine%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20f1%20%3D%20(new%20A).f%0D%0Af1()%20%2F%2F%20-%3E%20undefined%0D%0A)

Comment: I'll add that [this suggestion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968) would give a compile error on `let f1 = (new A).f`.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen That link seems really helpful. I'll read the related pages to get a deeper understanding of the design of `this` type. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> So in my opinion, the inferred type of this inside f() should be this: any, not this: this.

well, yes. In some ways you're right. It is not 100% sure that `this` inside a class function is really an instance of the class. But *typescript is not meant to be 100% accurate*! This is important to understand! The type guarantees don't hold in all situations. They literally can't.

Javascript is *very* dynamic. There is no way to just analyze all this dynamics at compile time.

So Typescript purely relies on assumptions and user provided type information. It should help you, but wont stop you when you want to shoot into your own feet.

Just never do this:

```
const x = foo.x;
x();
```

---

actually this has the effect that older class models then ES6 classes like the ember object model are very hard to use with typescript - the assumptions just dont hold up. And even the best typings have limitations. There are things you can do in JS you can not define in TS. Still TS can be very helpful for all other cases.

Answer (score 1):

Great question. Typescript has what we call an unsound type system. (Closure Compiler and Flow also have unsound type systems.) An unsound type system means that Typescript will sometimes compute a type for an expression that is wrong; it is different from the type that the expression will take at runtime. As mentioned in the other reply, this happens because JavaScript is very dynamic, and type-system designers take a few shortcuts in order to tame the complexity.

In your particular example, even though `this` can indeed by `any`, in practice it is almost always `A`, so that's what Typescript chooses. However, it could potentially warn at `f1()`, because the method is called as a function (i.e., without a `this`).